# Grafana not working properly with loadbalancer

Tags: load-balancing, grafana

Getting the following error while trying to access the grafana loadbalancer url:

If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build
4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you show us your grafana configuration? https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1

Comment: these are the two grafana instances: https://<server1.example.com>:3000/
https://<server2.example.com>:3000/

this is the loadbalancer url:

https://<serverlb.example.com>:3000/

please let me know if any other details are needed

this is the root url provided:
domain = example.com

;enforce_domain = false

root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/

;serve_from_sub_path = false

Comment: F5 load balancer is used